# Did anyone has any idea why sql server 2014 not responding after 2 to3 time execution of database script on same database in java project

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2014-express

In my project have different organizations, for that i have created test cases using TestNG and this all test cases are called from TestAll class, each organization test case needs different database script.

> So when i execute that TestAll class it needs to execute database scripts more then one time on same database.
>   After executing script 2 to 3 times, my test case execution getting stopped.... and it will not continue further execution.

Comment: Stopped? Because of what? Any errors, Stacktraces from your Test cases? Without these details, no one will be able to help you!

Comment: There is not any error, just database stop responding.... can it happens because establishing database connection multiple time (some of them may close or not close)within some seconds....

Comment: May be an issue with parallel execution of the scripts on the same database, code not handled that properly!